# Get number of tables in word docx

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I'm using python-docx to parse tables from .doc(x) files. I don't see a method for counting the number of tables in the file. I'm wanting to iterate through every table for a specific cell entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple count of tables in a Word document can be done like this:

```
document = Document("having-tables.docx")
table_count = len(document.tables)
```

If you want to iterate over all tables in the document it's:

```
for table in document.tables:
    # ---do_something_to(table)---
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a ‘table’ property on the ‘Document’ object that should allow you to iterate through all the tableS in a document.

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#id1